# Errors while installing Yeoman (npm install -g yo)

Tags: node.js, yeoman

I get the errors below when I run `npm install -g yo` on my windows command line. Any ideas on what I need to do to get a clean install of Yeoman?

```
C:\Users\zmacomber\AppData\Roaming\npm\bower -> C:\Users\zmacomber\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\bin\bower
npm ERR! peerinvalid The package yo does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer generator-angular@0.8.0 wants yo@>=1.0.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer generator-angular-phonegap-seed@0.6.0 wants yo@>=1.0.0-rc.1
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer generator-jhipster@0.18.1 wants yo@>=1.2.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer generator-karma@0.7.0 wants yo@>=1.0.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer generator-meanjs@0.1.5 wants yo@>=1.0.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer generator-mocha@0.1.3 wants yo@>=1.0.0-rc.1.1
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer generator-ng-cordova@0.0.0 wants yo@>=1.0.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer generator-webapp@0.4.9 wants yo@>=1.0.0

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "yo"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\zmacomber\git
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.18
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.8
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\zmacomber\git\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Are you using jhipster as well?

Comment: Yes - I'm using JHipster as well

Comment: In the github they say to update the yo to 1.2.0. Anyway, if you go to the generator-jhipster folder and switch the yo version to 1.1.2 will fix this

Comment: Wow those are some old versions of generators.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to update nodejs to be able to install the 1.2.0 version of yo.